# Opening a PDF File by script, printing it, and closing it

Tags: command-line, scripts, printing, pdf

A friend of mine got some PDF files infected with malware.  He figured out that if he opens them on Ubuntu and prints them back to a file it removes the malware.

Anyone know if there is a way to script the opening, printing, and closing of a directory of PDF files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

**Firstly:**

Install a PDF printer, run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install cups-pdf
```

**Secondly:**

In the terminal, `cd` into the directory containing your PDF files and run the following command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec lpr -P PDF {} \;
```

**Done:**

The printed files are located in your home directory under a directory called `PDF`.

---

**Important notice:**

When you install the PDF printer in the first step above ( by default ) it is named **PDF** as the name that identifies the printer in the system and the command in the second step above should work fine with no errors.

However if that is not the case on your system or if you had to remove and add the printer again, the name of the printer might change and you will get an error like `lpr: No such file or directory`. To solve this you need to find the new name for your PDF printer. This is how to do it:

- Type this in the terminal and hit enter:

  `lpstat -s`
- You will see output like this:

  `device for CUPS-PDF-Printer: cups-pdf:/`
- Your printers name is now **CUPS-PDF-Printer** and you need to modify the command in the second step accordingly, like so:

  `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec lpr -P CUPS-PDF-Printer {} \;`

---

**Explanation - as requested by [user3140225](https://askubuntu.com/users/618353/user3140225):**

```
{}
```

Contains the output of the `find` command.

To see it in action:

- Please run `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo {} \;` from within a directory that contains some files in it.
- Then run `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` from within the same directory.

The output is the same.

```
\
```

Prevents the semicolon `;` after it from being interpreted as a shell punctuation which will prematurely terminate the command.

```
;
```

Indicates the end of the argument part for `-exec` which is needed for it to work correctly.

Comment: `lpr` accepts multiple files, so `lpr -P PDF *.pdf` or – if there are *a lot* of files and it’s exceeding the shell’s `ARG_MAX` limit – `printf '%s\0' *.pdf | xargs -0 'lpr -P PDF'` saves the `find` call.

Comment: @dessert **Must use find**. I tried what you suggested in your comment and it did not work. Also the PDF printer will stop printing afterwords and has to be reinstalled.

Comment: This is almost too good!!  Thank you!!

Comment: @Raffa can you please explain the `{} \;` at the end?

Comment: @user3140225 The `{}` contains the output of the `find` command. To see it in action, run `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo {} \;` from within a directory that contains some files and then run `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` from within the same directory, the output is the same. The backslash  is there to prevent the semicolon `;` after it from being interpreted as a shell punctuation which will prematurely terminate the command. The semicolon `;` indicates the end of the argument part for `-exec` which is needed for it to work correctly.

Comment: When we are trying it, it outputs the PDF but all the pages are empty.  So for example if its a 5 page PDF, 5 pages come out but they have not content - any ideas?

Comment: @Ole Does it do this for all PDF files or some of them? Have you tried opening the original PDF file that has blank pages on Ubuntu and seeing if it displays any content? This could happen if the original PDF file is corrupted or password protected.

Comment: HI @Raffa - We downloaded a sample PDF from comcast to try out, and it comes out empty.

Comment: @Ole Was the original file empty? If not, please link it here if possible so I can address the issue. I have just tried the command again on a bunch of  varying PDF files and it printed them all.

Comment: @Raffa - Never mind - My friend is running it on a Virtual Machine and he's having problem.  I tried it on a real install and it works fine.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Raffa thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @user3140225 You are most welcome.